# Adobe CQ / AEM Informations

Tags: adobe, aem

We are studying the possibility of changing our current website to the AEM platform and i have some general questions that i couldn't find on Google.

1) We are a language school and we offer several courses, we have all the website data on SQL Server. I saw that i can create components on AEM to use on the visual editor, would i be able to, let's say create a component to display the HTML from my DB on a page or create a component to create the HTML i have on the DB ? Would i be able to create an component to show my last news automatically ? To show all my news on a pagination page ?

2) We also have registration pages where you can enroll and get some discount, we have this as an form that will post this information to an third part API and receive a return, redirect the page and go to the second step. Would i be able to reproduce this with AEM ?

3) How components are created ? I don't need an 101, just the basics so i can understand how it works and how can i use it to solve my problems.

I have tried almost everything on the web, there aren't many courses, tutorials and trainings and the manual isn't really friendly.

Do you know any good course besides Adobe ? It's really expensive and they aren't available on my country.

Comment: Why was it down voted ? Care to explain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you have considered all options before choosing AEM. AEM is an enterprise web cms and comes with a price. The consulting and training services are also expensive.

Other than Adobe, there are several sites that has loads of information and resources on AEM. I tried to compile them here http://www.practicalaem.com/category/references/

On youtube you can find several sessions on using AEM.

Comment: In this case i don't have other choices since my client wants to use it, i'm going to taje a look at this. Thank you